# Populate an array with items from a List of objects using a loop

Tags: c#

I have a list of type `Product`. . .

```
public List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
```

. . . and I want to create a method `GetList(string theType)` that will populate an array with items from that `List` if the `theType` argument supplied with the method matches the `Type` field inside any of the objects in the `List`.

Only thing I want the array to contain when it is returned are the **names** of all the products that were matched successfully against the supplied `theType` argument.

```
   public string[] GetList(string theType)
        {
            string[] theList = new string[10];
            for(int i = 0; i < theList.Length; i++)
            {
                foreach (Product p in products)
                {
                    if (p.Type.Equals(theType))
                    {
                        theList[i] = p.ProductName; 
                    }
                }
            }
            return theList;
        }
```

This doesn't seem to work. Even I can see it. I am just too tired to think this out.

**EDIT:**

I want to populate a combobox with the returned `theList`.
There are two comboboxes. You have to select a preset value in the first one in order to enable and second one which should be populated with products items of type that was selected in combobox1. I only have one event handling for combobox1:

```
    private void combobox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (combobox1.Text != "")
                {
                    combobox2.Enabled = true;
                    combobox2.Items.Clear();

                    if (combobox1.SelectedText.Equals("Dairy"))
                    {
// i try to display what the method has returned inside a messagebox, but it doesn't display it at all, the messagebox
                        string[] theList = client.GetList("dairy");
                        string theStringList = "";

                        for (int i = 0; i < theList.Length; i++)
                        {
                            theStringList += "\n" + theList[i];
                        }
                        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}"), theStringList);
                        //combobox2.Items.AddRange(client.GetList("dairy"));
                    }
                }
                else
                    combobox2.Enabled = false;
            }
```

Comment: edited my answer to accommodate for your edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With LINQ:

```
return products.Where(p => p.Type == theType).Select(p => p.ProductName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know how many items will match, use a `List<string>` rather than an array:

```
public IList<string> GetList(string theType)
{
    List<string> matchingProductNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (Product p in products)
    {
        if (p.Type == theType)
           matchingProductNames.Add(p.ProductName);
    }
    return matchingProductNames;
}
```

This alternatively also can be done in a much more expressive way (in my opinion) with Linq:

```
string[] productNames = products.Where(p => p.Type == theType)
                                .Select(p => p.ProductName)
                                .ToArray();
```

You currently display the text content as **caption** of your message box since it is the second parameter to `MessageBox.Show` - since you first character is a newline though **you will not see anything**:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}"), theStringList);
```

You probably *meant to* write `MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", theStringList))` but there is no point in using `string.Format` here in the first place since you don't apply formatting, just use the string directly:

```
string theStringList = string.Join("\n", client.GetList("dairy"));
MessageBox.Show(theStringList, "some caption");
```

Comment: I tried everything that was suggested here. Problem is I want to use that returned `theList` to populate a combobox using the `AddRange()`, but it doesn't update.

Comment: you should show the related code then - also make sure that your method in fact does return matching items

Comment: I have updated the original post with the code for event handling of the combobox1.

Comment: I tried to display a messagebox with the contents of an array but it appears epmty.

Comment: what is the content of `products` at the time?

Comment: `products` has 3 objects of type `Product`. Each of those object have `productName` and `type` data members with their appropriate properties. 2 of them are of `dairy` type the other one is `fruit`.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! I also noticed that all three objects had a mistake. Fixed it now and get a messagebox displayed properly with my items. But why isn't the combobox2 populated with these items when I select a predefined type(Dairy, for example) from the first combobox like mentioned in the original post of the combobox1 handling. Is the event I'm handling wrong? I wanted to make the second combobox to be disabled if nothing was selected in the first one which works. But if I select `Dairy` - second combobox only becomes enabled but empty without any items. I used AddRange of combobox - nothing.

Answer (score 1):

why are you putting it in a for loop?

```
public List<String> GetList(string theType)
    {
        List<String> TheList = new List<String>();

            foreach (Product p in products)
            {
                if (p.Type = theType))
                {
                    theList.add(ProductName); 
                }
            }

        return theList;
    }
```

Then for your edit (populating a combo box)

you should use a foreach loop after getting the list

```
List<String> iList = GetList("typenamehere")

    foreach(string s in theList){
    Combobox1.Add(s);
    }
```

then on selection change you can check the combobox.selecteditem.text

Answer (score 1):

```
public string[] GetList(String theType)
    {
        ArrayList theList = new ArrayList();
        foreach (Product p in products)
        {
            if (p.GetType().ToString() == theType)
                theList.Add(p.ProductName);
        }
        return theList.Cast<string>().ToArray();
    }
```